# Why does "unset" work on environmental variables?

Tags: bash, scope, cygwin, environment-variables

It was my understanding that `set` is for setting shell variables.  And..
it was my understanding that `export` is for setting environmental variables.

So, is there any good reason why `unset` will delete environmental variables, but not shell variables?

E.g. when I export a variable via `export VAR='something'` I can then do `unset VAR` and I do `printenv`, and I see that it isn't listed anymore.

However, I can't find the equivalent for deleting local variables?  Or is `unset` a misnomer?  Thanks.

Comment: `unset VAR` will unset the variable whether it be local or environmental.  Try: `VAR=xyz; set; unset VAR; set` and note that VAR appears in the first lot of output from `set` and not in the second.

Comment: `export` simply 'annotates' the variable as to-be-exported; it's the *same* variable and is affected by `unset` in the same manner.

Comment: These links might help clarify: [Difference between environment variables and exported environment variables in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b), [What do the bash-builtins 'set' and 'export' do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71144/what-do-the-bash-builtins-set-and-export-do).  Note that the specifics might vary with other shells (Bourne, Korn, etc).  Note, too, that "set" is basically a "different" kind of beast.

Comment: What is the difference between shell variables & environmental variables? Are you referring to built-in / special variables as shell variables? (eg `UID`, `RANDOM` etc)

Comment: It is historical, contrast with the c-shell.  IMO one of the few things that is better in that shell is that environment variables are set with `setenv` and unset with `unsetenv`.  The following may be instructive: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7moj/index.html (does not describe bash).

Answer (score 1):

`unset VAR` will unset the variable whether it be local or environmental.  Try:

```
$ set | grep '^VAR='
$ VAR=xyz
$ set | grep '^VAR='
VAR=xyz
$ unset VAR
$ set | grep '^VAR='
$
```

Note that VAR appears in the first lot of output from `set` and not in the second.

For historical reasons if nothing else, you can create a variable, then export it.  Bash seems to have an inordinately elaborate output format for `export` which is reflected in the revised `grep` in the test below:

```
$ unset VAR
$ export | grep '^declare -x VAR='
$ VAR=xyz
$ set | grep '^VAR='
VAR=xyz
$ export | grep '^declare -x VAR='
$ export VAR
$ export | grep '^declare -x VAR='
declare -x VAR="xyz"
$ unset VAR
$ export | grep '^declare -x VAR='
$
```

The `set` command in Bourne shell and its derivatives (POSIX, Korn, Bash, etc) has very little to do with variables at all.

Comment: `export` without arguments is a synonym for `declare -x`. (And generally `export` and `declare -x` do the same thing, but only `export` is posix.) If you want to see the definition for a single variable (shell or environmental) you can use `declare -p varname` (which sets the status code to nonzero if `varname` isn't defined).

Comment: Fine; Bash can do what the hell it likes, but there are times when Bourne shell was simpler to understand, and this is one of those times.